# Sending attachments in Mandrill

Tags: email, base64, email-attachments, mandrill

I'm trying to send out an attachment with Mandrill. I've added this to my object:

```
    "attachments": [
      {
        "type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        "name": "filename-removed.docx"
        "content": attachment
      }
    ]
```

attachment is a massive string which I got when I uploaded the file to this base64 converter:

http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

I tried pasting the string right in there, as well as making it a variable (like above) but I keep getting this error. Is there an easier way of doing this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pasting the string in, try manipulating the file directly and encoding it into base64. In Python:

```
import base64

file = open(path/to/file.docx)
encoded = base64.b64encode(file.read())
file.close()
```

Then set your attachment equal to `encoded` and you should be good to go.

Alternatively, you may just need a comma after `"filename-removed.docx"`.